# How to see what files are being added by Setup utility

Tags: dll, installation

I'm not sure if what I'm asking for is ridiculous or not, but is it possible to see exactly what files are being extracted from the setup, and to where? e.i.: in Program Directory/   and  System32/ such as DLLs being registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645?ppud=4). It supports filters so you can see only the files written on disk.

If you want to use the extracted files in an installer, you will need a Repackager. Most commercial setup authoring tools include a repackaging tool.